# Index-coclosure for monoidal categories, generalizing products and lextensive coproducts

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

I found a kind of monoidal structure that generalizes cartesian product and lextensive coproduct, and I'm wondering if anyone has seen it before and/or can tell me about it. I'm calling this structure an *index-coclosure*.

Before defining it, the following will be useful.

For a category $\mathcal{C}$, let $\mathbf{Poly}_\mathcal{C}$ denote the coproduct completion of $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$. Its objects and morphisms are given by
\begin{align}
Ob(\mathbf{Poly}_\mathcal{C}) &= \{(I,c)\mid I\in\mathbf{Set}, c\colon I\to \mathcal{C}\}\\
\mathbf{Poly}_\mathcal{C}((I,c),(J,d))&=\prod_{i:I}\sum_{j:J}\mathcal{C}(d_j, c_i).
\end{align}
For example, one can check that $\mathbf{Poly}_0=1$, $\mathbf{Poly}_1=\mathbf{Set}$, and $\mathbf{Poly}_\mathbf{Set}$ is the usual category of polynomial functors in one variable. But again, it's just the coproduct completion of $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$. Anyway, on to the main definition!

**Definition:** An *index-coclosure* for a monoidal category $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ consists of a functor
$$
(I,c)\colon \mathcal{C}\times \mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}\to \mathbf{Poly}_\mathcal{C},
$$
and a natural isomorphism
$$
\mathcal{C}(X, Y\otimes Z)
\cong
\sum_{i:I(X,Y)}\mathcal{C}(c_i, Z).
$$

**Examples**

1. Any Cartesian category $(\mathcal{C},\times)$ is index-coclosed with
   $$
   I(X,Y):=\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\qquad \text{and}\qquad c_i:=X
   $$
   Indeed, we have
   $$
   \mathcal{C}(X,Y\times Z)\cong\sum_{i\colon \mathcal{C}(X,Y)}\mathcal{C}(X,Z).
   $$
2. Any extensive category $(\mathcal{C},+)$ with a terminal object $1$ (and in particular, any lextensive category) is index-coclosed with
   $$
   I(X,Y):=\mathcal{C}(X,Y+1)\qquad \text{and}\qquad c_i:=i^{-1}(1)
   $$
   Indeed, we have
   $$
   \mathcal{C}(X,Y+ Z)\cong\sum_{i\colon \mathcal{C}(X,Y+1)}\mathcal{C}(i^{-1}(1),Z).
   $$

There are many other examples (e.g. I know of two additional index coclosures on $\mathbf{Poly}_{\mathbf{Set}}$).

**Question** Do you know of any references for something like this? Any idea of a more canonical or elegant or just different way to think about it?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't checked all the details, but this looks very much like multi-coclosed structure, i.e. that the tensor product has a multi-left adjoint. See Definition 2.8 of [How nice are free completions of categories?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.02524), for instance (though your example is dual).